# Writing a rspec test for delete action in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a delete function in one of my controllers like below:

```
before_action :set_form, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 def destroy
    if @form.destroy
            render json: @form, status: :ok
        else
            render json: @form.errors, status: :not_found
        end
  end

 private

  def set_form
    @form = Form.find(params[:id])
  end

 end
```

I have two questions:

1) I'm returning 404 when delete is not correctly performed. Is this reasonable status code? I looked into all 4XX status code and this was making most sense.

2) I am not sure how I am gonna write a test for `render json: @form.errors, status: :not_found`.

Below is what I tried:

```
context "Cannot delete the model" do
    it "responds successfully with an HTTP 404 status code" do
        delete :destroy, id: 100000
        expect(response).to have_http_status(404)
    end
end
```

The problem is that I get an error saying `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:Couldn't find Visa with 'id'=10000` instead of `delete` action actually failing. How do I mock that `delete` action is failing?

Answer (score 1):

That error is the same error you'll get in development and even production.  The line...

```
@form = Form.find(params[:id])
```

Will raise an exception if no `Form` record is found with the delivered ID.

also if the `@form` is not found and you find a mechanism to continue, the `@form.destroy` will still not work because there's no method `destroy` on `nil` objects, and there's also no method `errors` on `nil` objects.

If you insist on handling destroy methods as you describe, you'd need to do something like...

```
before_action :set_form, only: [:show, :edit, :update] #remove destroy
def destroy
  @form = Form.find_by(id: params[:id])
  if @form
    @form.destroy
    render json: @form, status: :ok
  else
    render json: 'record not found for delete', status: :not_found
  end
end
```

Comment: doesn't find_by still return `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`?

Comment: No, `find` will raise, `find_by` will return `nil`.

Comment: yep, what @MichaelKohl says. Michael's answer is good, but you'll need to be prepared for the possibility of a nil object being received in most of your CRUD methods `:show`, `:edit`, `:update`

Comment: Unless you add a generic `resuce_from` for `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` in `ApplicationController`. Not saying this is the way to go, but I've seen this in several Rails projects.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the same. But again he then has to handle the case in all his methods that `@form` might be a `nil` object.  I don't think the OP is at the stage where he's ready to investigate that possibility, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your `set_form` method raises that error, you have to catch it there or use `find_by_id` in `destroy`.

```
def set_form
  @form = Form.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
end
```

This way `@form` will be `nil` in your `if`.

As for HTTP status code, you might consider using [422](http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity).

Comment: is `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` just returning @form as nil if it cannot be found? And is this considered a hacky way or not? Never encountered this before so I would love to know more about this approach.

Comment: It's rescuing the exception and doing nothing (a `def` is an implicit `begin` for a `begin-rescue-end` block). Instance variables are always initialized to `nil`. I just wanted to show you were the problem is, you can of course also rescue in `destroy` and put the `render json: @form.errors, status: :not_found` bit there.

Comment: This raises another problem. How do I test when `destroy` action is failing? How do I mock this behavior in rspec to test `render json: @form.errors, status: :not_found`? And is erran handling even needed for `destroy` function?

Comment: `allow(Form).to receive(:find).and_raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)` for example: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/raising-an-error

Comment: I acknowledge that part. What I'm really asking is how to test `render json: @form.errors, status: :not_found` part. When I run simple cov, I see that part is not covered by rspec. I would like to cover it so I can have 100% coverage. But not sure how to test it since i do not know how to make the `destroy` to purposely fail.

Answer (score 0):

Rails will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` when you call `.find` on a record with an invalid id. This is a very desirable behaviour since it provides a nice catch-all for when a resource cannot be found.

The default is to send a 404 - not found header. For the HTML request type it also sends a default error page.

Rather the issue is how you are testing it.

If you want to test that rails raises the error:

```
context "Cannot delete the model" do
  it "raises an error when the id is not valid" do
    bypass_rescue
    expect { delete :destroy, id: 100000 }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
    expect(response).to have_http_status(404)
  end
end
```

However if you want to test that deleting the model fails for any other reason (record is locked or user is not authorized for example) you should set up a record in the database with fixtures or factories and provide a valid id - you should also provide the correct response code (422 or 401).

As to mocking the delete failure you can use `allow_any_instance_of(SomeModel).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false)`.

Comment: Do you mind providing an extra example of a test covering `render json: @form.errors, status: :not_found`? Let's say i have found a one valid model. However, the `destroy` function fails for some reason and hits the above line I wrote. How do I test this case in rspec?  Additionally, I get 200 if I follow your sample test. I also get `200` from your example `allow_any_instance_of(SomeModel).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false)`.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can answer my above questions!